# undefined index (opencart)

Tags: php, opencart

I'm trying to add a new input text in opencart,
my view ***payment_method.tpl*** I added

```
<label><?php echo $text_comments; ?></label>
<textarea name="comment" rows="8" style="width: 98%;"><?php echo $comment; ?></textarea>

 <label><?php echo $text_referred; ?></label> // My Code
 <input type="text" name="referred" value="<?php echo $referred; ?>" />
```

In Controller ***payment_method.tpl*** I added

```
if (!$json) {
                $this->session->data['payment_method'] = $this->session->data['payment_methods'][$this->request->post['payment_method']];
                $this->session->data['comment'] = strip_tags($this->request->post['comment']);
                $this->session->data['referred'] = $this->request->post['referred']; //My Code
            }
```

and

```
if (isset($this->session->data['referred'])) {
            $this->data['referred'] = $this->session->data['referred']; //Variable
        } else {
            $this->data['referred'] = '';
        }
```

In My model ***Order.php***

```
$this->db->query("INSERT INTO `" . DB_PREFIX . "order` SET invoice_prefix = '" . $this->db->escape($data['invoice_prefix']) . "',  referred = '" . $this->db->escape($data['referred']) . "',
```

My error logs show

```
2014-09-21 12:57:42 - PHP Notice:  Undefined index:  referred in /home/dlars/public_html/tempdir/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-catalog_controller_checkout_payment_method.php on line 212
2014-09-21 12:57:42 - PHP Notice:  Undefined index:  referred in /home/dlars/public_html/tempdir/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-catalog_model_checkout_order.php on line 4
```

I gather whatever is on my view isn't being posted to my controller, however I'm not sure where else I can define referred.
I thought with OC whatever is defined inside the view, it's posted to the controller?

Someone please help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is obvious. The new *referred* input is not passed via HTTP AJAX request. This is caused in a different template - `checkout.tpl`. Open it up, scroll to the end and search for this JS callback:

```
$('#button-payment-method').live('click', function() {
```

Here find the line

```
data: $('#payment-method input[type=\'radio\']:checked, #payment-method input[type=\'checkbox\']:checked, #payment-method textarea'),
```

and change it to:

```
data: $('#payment-method input[type=\'radio\']:checked, #payment-method input[type=\'checkbox\']:checked, #payment-method textarea, #payment-method input[type=\'text\']'),
```

Now the value should be passed via AJAX request and should be set for the `referred` indexes.

Comment: Nice! looked around and no mention of it anywhere